# how do I sort a data by keyword using FIELD in sql

Tags: mysql

I have this table

[image: Table]

And I want to sort the MonthAndYear column.

I tried using this query

```
SELECT * FROM BranchProfitsMonth ORDER BY FIELD(MonthandYear,'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','Ausgust','September','October','November','December') ASC;
```

but the result is this

[image: Result]

the expected result should be like this

| Branch | MontAndYear | Payments | Expenses | Profits |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jacinto MRT | December, 2022 | 2000 | 0 | 2000 |
| Maligno | December, 2022 | 10000 | 1020 | 8980 |
| Maligno | November, 2022 | 1333 | 0 | 1333 |
| Maligno | January, 2023 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| Santo | December, 2022 | 0 | 11640 | -11640 |
| Santo | January, 2023 | 0 | 100 | -100 |

Here is the table for testing

```
CREATE TABLE `BranchProfitsMonth` (
  `Branch` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `MonthAndYear` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Payments` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Expenses` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Profits` int(11) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `BranchProfitsMonth` (`Branch`, `MonthAndYear`, `Payments`, `Expenses`, `Profits`) VALUES
('Maligno', 'December, 2022', 10000, 1020, 8980),
('Maligno', 'January, 2023', 1000, 0, 1000),
('Maligno', 'November, 2022', 1333, 0, 1333),
('Jacinto MRT', 'December, 2022', 2000, 0, 2000),
('Santo', 'December, 2022', 0, 11640, -11640),
('Santo', 'January, 2023', 0, 100, -100);
```

Comment: *I tried using this query* You did `ORDER BY 0`.

Comment: that is the part where I can't sort it by keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM BranchProfitsMonth
ORDER BY Branch, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', MonthAndYear), '%d %M, %Y');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Y6-2WZgE)

Comment: it works so well thanks akina for the second time helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to construct "May 2022" from "2022/05/01" and then simply `ORDER BY` that column.  I suggest you store it as a `DATE` to make that easy.

To split the year from "May 2022", try `SUBSTRING_INDEX(..., -1)`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion I might consider it on my next project. I can store it as a date but the thing is, I will not be able to group it by month and year because if I  try to GROUP BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Month(MonthAndYear), YEAR(MonthAndYear)), '%d %M, %Y') 
it will always provide the missing day in a MonthAndYear

Comment: @JohnAlsaceMondoñedo - `GROUP BY LEFT(dt, 7) ORDER BY dt` where the column `dt` is something like "2022/05/01".  (Tack on `DESC` to have the latest first.)